# Drools 5.1 memory issues

Tags: java, memory-leaks, drools

Can drool 5.1 cause memory leak  issues?
We are using complex validation rules where we are calling java codes.
Each request to backend load 2-3 drool files and new KnowledgeBase  is created for each request.

Can anyone throw more light on this?

```
private void initRulesEngine() {
    kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    if (kbuilder != null) {
        kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    }
}

public void executeRules(BaseUOW requestedUOW) {
    initRulesEngine();
    ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    ksession.insert(requestedUOW);
    ksession.fireAllRules();
}
```

This is our code for Drool rules

Comment: I can't remember offhand what we profiled our Drools app at memory-wise, but it's a documented fact that the knowledge base is a heavy weight. Why are you creating a new one for each request? Normally you initialize one KB at app startup and then reuse it for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Yes, what about your sessions? Are you creating a KBase and a KSession per request?
CHeers

Comment: @salaboy yes we are creating a KBase and a KSession per request

Comment: @Perception we can create one KB but ,we are facing issue in managing session then

Comment: @Vish - you need a knowledge session per user yes, but each of those can be created from the same KB. Don't forget to cleanup and dispose the session when you are done with it to avoid possibility of leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of profiling and did not found any memory leak in Drools 5.1. If you are using stateful sessions, make sure you call dispose() after using them. Caching kbases is also recomended if possible, but creating them on demand should not leak memory anyway.

Other than that, it is just like any other java application. Use a profiler to find out what class (if any) is retaining your object instances in memory.