# Memory leak issue in Kie Session Drools 6.1.X

Tags: java, ejb, drools

I am using state full KieSession in drools 6.1.X. I observed following behaviors about memory usage by KieSession :

In normal load test, it is working fine and avg. processing time is ok. I am also retracting all the inserted fact except some fact that is required always in the session. 
However, memory usage is increasing sequentially. We guess that this is due to the fact that KieSession is still holding information about inserted facts.

Moreover, we are doing insertion and retraction on each requests. This causes increase in memory usage and on some point of time, processing is very slow and thus creating performance issue in rule engine.

When I am creating a new session after disposing of the current session, the memory usage will be very low as a fresh one and again it is increasing sub sequentially.

Please suggest some work around or is this a bug in KieSession API.

Thanks
Shorav

Comment: have a look at this, its for 5.1 though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498502/drools-5-1-memory-issues?rq=1

Comment: Use a simple listener and count inserts and retracts, compute the difference. If this value increases, you miss some facts.

Comment: @laune I tried same way but still some facts remains in the session even if I retracted all the facts inserted. This extra facts increase over a period of time and hence creating memory leak issue. Even When I am calling getFactHandles().size() it returns some number but when iterating and checking hasNext() method, it is returning false. Please suggest.